# How to check whether the date coming in $_POST array is not greater than today's date in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, date, date-comparison

The date to be checked is as follows :

```
$submission_date = 12-25-2014; //The date in mm-dd-yyyy format that is to be tested against today's date
```

Now I want to echo the error message since the date contained in a variable `$submission_date` is a future date.

How should I do this efficiently and effectively using PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can turn future data into a `timestamp` and the compare that turned `timestamp` against current one. Done

Comment: Please don't change to a different question after others have already taken the time to answer! Just open a new question if necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the issue in a code written for comparing the date with today's date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394548/whats-the-issue-in-a-code-written-for-comparing-the-date-with-todays-date)

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this (use DateTime::createFromFormat() to control exact format of input dates, for example) but perhaps the simplest that suits the example is:

```
$isFuture = (strtotime($submission_date) > strtotime($_POST['current_date']))
```

Note that OP changed the question. If desired date to test against is not in $_POST array, just replace `strtotime($_POST['current_date'])` with `time()` to use current system time.

To compare against current date, disregarding time of day, use:

```
$today = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
// $today = new DateTime("today");  // better solution courtesy of Glavić
// see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php for more info
$today_timestamp = $today->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: I've changed my question. Now no date is coming as a current date in $_POST array then?

Comment: @PHPLover That's another question. His answer answers your question

Comment: OP removed the part of the question that had the $_POST['current_date'] specified, but you can get current timestamp with `time()`

Comment: $_POST['current_date'] is no more existing now.

Comment: and now I've answered your revised question with my edit, as well.

Comment: yes, you have answered but again you are comparing the $submission date with $_POST['current_date']. I want to compare it with today's date. How to do this?

Comment: Please re-read the last sentence of what I posted. Just use the `time()` function.

Comment: I want to compare with today's date not with current time. Can you please correct your comment accordingly?

Comment: do you mean you want to ignore hours, minutes, and seconds, and just test the date portion only?

Comment: Yes, I only want today's date to compare with.

Comment: Why do you mix DateTime and date functions? Where did you learn that, because a lot of users here use this bad approach? Just use keyword 'today' when creating DateTime object with time set to 00:00:00!

Comment: @Glavić excellent, I just looked that up and it's clearly a better solution. Will edit above.

Comment: Second bad thing here is, that format `m-d-Y` is not valid format, and `strtotime()` function will return `false`. [See demo here](https://eval.in/232746).

Comment: @Glavić I wrote `'Y-m-d'` not `'m-d-Y'`, what are you driving at?

Comment: `strtotime($submission_date)` where from OP question, `$submission_date` is in `m-d-Y` format.

Comment: Ah yes, necessary to use DateTime::createFromFormat() or date_create_from_format() to properly parse that; can't feed directly into strtotime(). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If posted format is in `m-d-Y`, then you cannot convert it to unix timestamp directly with `strtotime()` function, because it [will return `false`](https://eval.in/232759).

If you need to use `strtotime()` then [change the input format to `m/d/Y` by simple `str_replace()`](https://eval.in/232756).

On the other hand, you could use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, where you can directly compare objects:

```php
$submission_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-d-Y', $submission_date);
$today_date = new DateTime('today');

if ($submission_date > $today_date) {
    echo "submission_date is in the future\n";
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/232758)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

With PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) you can check whether the input date is future or old w.r.to the todate.

```
$submission_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $submission_date);
$submission_date = $submission_date->format('Y-m-d');
$current_date    = new DateTime('today');
$current_date    = $current_date->format('Y-m-d');

if ($submission_date > $current_date)
{
       echo "Future date";
}
else
{
       echo "Old date";
}
```

Comment: No current date is coming in $_POST array. Then how to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't it the same answer?

Comment: $_POST['current_date'] is no  more existing now. Then how to check the $submission date with today's date?

Comment: $current_date = date('m-d-Y');

Comment: I tried your code but the error message is coming even if the date is lesser than the current date, say if I compared the date 12-08-2014 then also I'm getting the error which shouldn't happen. If I enter the today's date i.e. 12-10-2014 only then the error message is not coming. How to fix this?

Comment: if i tried with submission_date = '12-08-2014' then i am getting "old date"

Comment: Format `m-d-Y` is not valid format, and `strtotime()` function will return `false`. [See demo here](https://eval.in/232746).

Comment: You can compare DateTime objects, no need to format it, like in my answer. But ok, there should be different answers, and this one also works.