# What's the issue in a code written for comparing the date with today's date?

Tags: php, date, comparison, date-comparison

I'm comparing a date with current date(i.e. today's date). It is expected that the error should come only when the date to be compared is greater than today's date. It should not come for date which is less than or equal to today's date.

I've written following code for it.

```
$submission_date = $_POST['submission_date']; //The date in mm-dd-yyyy format that is to be tested against today's date. The value in $submission date is 12-25-2014 
//This is a future date. Today's date is 12-10-2014 in dd-mm-yyyy format

$current_date = date('m-d-Y');

if (strtotime($submission_date) > strtotime($current_date))
{
   echo "Future date not accepted";
}
```

With the above code I'm not getting errors for future dates, sometimes I'm getting error for previous dates as well.

How to optimize and make this code correct and standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If posted format is in `m-d-Y`, then you cannot convert it to unix timestamp directly with `strtotime()` function, because it [will return `false`](https://eval.in/232759).

If you need to use `strtotime()` then [change the input format to `m/d/Y` by simple `str_replace()`](https://eval.in/232756).

On the other hand, you could use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, where you can directly compare objects:

```php
$submission_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-d-Y', $submission_date);
$today_date = new DateTime('today');

if ($submission_date > $today_date) {
    echo "submission_date is in the future\n";
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/232758)</kbd>

If you need to extract some information from DateTime objects, use [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method on them, which accepts same format as [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```php
echo $today_date->format('m/d/Y'); # 12/11/2014
echo $today_date->format('m-d-Y'); # 12-11-2014
echo $today_date->format('Y-m-d'); # 2014-12-11
echo $today_date->format('Y-Y-Y'); # 2014-2014-2014
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/233354)</kbd>

Comment: Perfect answer with useful information. Thank you so much for the help you provided and the knowledge you shared. Surely it will going to benefit the PHP community. Thanks once again.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to compare date in 'Y-m-d' or 'd-m-Y' format. I think it is not possible to compare date in 'm-d-Y' format

Answer (score -1):

As we have made changes in your code and we test it works from my side so can you try below.

```
$submission_date = $_POST['submission_date'];
$current_date = date('d-m-y H:i:s');
if (strtotime($submission_date) > strtotime($current_date))
{
   echo "Future date not accepted";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That can't work because the submission date is in mm-dd-yyyy format. PHP will assume it's dd-mm-yyyy because it's got dashes. So if the submission date is 10th of December, the strtotime will return a unix timestamp for 12th of October.