# Why the strtotime() is not returning anything in following scenario?

Tags: php, date, timestamp, strtotime

I'm having one $_POST array data field containing the date in mm-dd-YYYY format as follows:

```
$_POST['submission_date'] => 12-15-2014 //I get this after I did print_r($_POST);
```

Now I tried following code with strtotime() but it's returning nothing . Why?

```
echo "Submission Date ".strtotime($_POST['submission_date']);
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the output of the echo??

Comment: @sgt:It's showing blank.

Comment: can you add the other code around it??

Comment: You mean it doesn't even print `Submission date `?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: The timestamp value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the issue in a code written for comparing the date with today's date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394548/whats-the-issue-in-a-code-written-for-comparing-the-date-with-todays-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If posted format is in `m-d-Y`, then you cannot convert it to unix timestamp directly with `strtotime()` function, because it [will return `false`](https://eval.in/232759).

If you need to use `strtotime()` then [change the input format to `m/d/Y` by simple `str_replace()`](https://eval.in/232756).

On the other hand, you could use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```php
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-d-Y', $submission_date);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d'), " or ", $dt->getTimestamp();
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/232790)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

**[Reference](http://php.net/strtotime)**

Is it so difficult to read documentation? You probably spent more time typing your question... and missed all the other interesting trivia

Answer (score 0):

**Answer updated**

Just add a string replace

```
$dbDate = str_replace('-', '/', $_POST['submission_date']);
```

Everything will work.

Your Date format is [American month, day and year](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

And requires `/` as separator not `-`

[Working Demo based on your input.](http://codepad.org/Emcu1AfI)

Comment: Your demo is wrong, since you are replacing already ok date. Other than that, this is valid answer IMHO.

Comment: @Glavić, apologies, I have changed the link.