# How to resolve this error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /var/www/web/print.php on line 9"?

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-comparison

I want to show error message if the date in a specific variable is greater than today's date. For it I wrote following code but it's gigiving the error:
**"Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /var/www/web/print.php on line 9"**

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  $form_data['trans_date'] = '12-11-2014';
  $newTransDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-d-Y', $form_data['trans_date']);
  $today_date = new DateTime();
  echo "Trans Date " . $newTransDate; die; //This is line no.9
  if($newTransDate > $today_date)
    echo "Error";
  else
    echo "Success";  
?>
```

What modifications need to be done to the above code in order to function everything with proper comparison of two dates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the issue in a code written for comparing the date with today's date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394548/whats-the-issue-in-a-code-written-for-comparing-the-date-with-todays-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `->format()` on that created DateTime object if your intent is to get the date that you want.

```
echo "Trans Date " . $newTransDate->format('Y-m-d'); // and remove that die!
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But please let me know whether the code I written for comparing two dates is correct?

Comment: @PHPLover yes, there is no problem with the way you are comparing the two datetime objects in your if.

Answer (score 0):

Because,

```
echo "Trans Date " . $newTransDate; die; //This is line no.9
```

`$newTransDate` is an object and your printing it with `echo`, a function dedicated to print string.

You can print it with:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newTransDate);
echo '</pre>';
```

[echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

[print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help. But is my code for comparing dates and putting messages properly written?