# How can I compare the date with today's date using UNIX timestamp values in PHP?

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp, date-comparison

I've following variable containing date in **MM-DD-YYYY** format. I want to compare this date with today's date. If the date containing in a variable is greater than the today's date I want to echo "Error" and if it is less than or equal to today's date I want to echo "Success".
For this thing I **don't want to use DateTime class**.

I think using UNIX Timestamp values could be a better option. If yo have any other better and efficient option you are welcome.

Following is the variable containing date in `MM-D-YYYY format`

```
$form_data['reg_date'] = '12-11-2014'; //This is today's date i.e. 11th December 2014
```

If the variable `$form_data['reg_date']` contains date greater than today's date(i.e. 11th December 2014) it should give error message otherwise should echo success message.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the issue in a code written for comparing the date with today's date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394548/whats-the-issue-in-a-code-written-for-comparing-the-date-with-todays-date)

Comment: `For this thing I don't want to use DateTime class.` why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've following variable containing date in MM-DD-YYYY format. I want to compare this date with today's date.

You cannot compare string representation of date in format `m-d-Y`. This format is invalid format, and php will not understand it. **[Read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) what date formats are valid**.

Best way to compare string dates is to have it in format `Y-m-d` or convert your string date to unix timestamp integer. But once you have date in `Y-m-d` format, it is trivial to convert it to unix timestamp, so converting it to timestamp just for comparing is an unnecessary step.

Convert `m-d-Y` to `m/d/Y` format, and then to unix timestamp:

```php
$date = '12-25-2014';
$date = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
var_dump($date);
var_dump(strtotime($date));

if (strtotime($date) > strtotime('today')) echo "ERROR";
else echo "SUCCESS";
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/233363)</kbd>

But this I already explained in [answer of your previous/same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27395846/67332) (see 2nd link).

> I think using UNIX Timestamp values could be a better option. If yo have any other better and efficient option you are welcome.

Other method could be converting format with [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) function:

```php
$date = '12-25-2014';
sscanf($date, "%d-%d-%d", $m, $d, $Y);
$date = "$Y-$m-$d";
var_dump($date);

if ($date > date('Y-m-d')) echo "ERROR";
else echo "SUCCESS";
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/233364)</kbd>

But I would still recommend you to use [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), like I already explained if [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27395846/67332).

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code

```
if(strtotime(date('d-m-Y')) == strtotime($form_data['reg_date'])){
        echo 'Today\'s Date';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First you have to convert your date in timestamp value like

```
$date_time = strtotime("11-12-2014");
```

and then you can do this to compare today date with the date you have.

```
$diff = $date_time - time();
```

This will gives you the date difference in seconds.